# How to set default timestamp to now() + n days?

Tags: postgresql

I am developing an auth flow, where tokens with expiry timestamp are used. 
When a user logs in successfully, a token is generated and saved in the DB.

I know I can add `expires` timestamp that is equal to `now()`, but how do I add `n` hours/days to it automatically?

Comment: `now() + '2 days'::interval`?.. (hours/month whatever)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

eg:

```
t=# create table t5(t timestamp default now() + '1 day'::interval);
CREATE TABLE
t=# insert into t5 default values;
INSERT 0 1
t=# select now(),t from t5;
              now              |             t
-------------------------------+----------------------------
 2018-01-26 08:05:06.641249+00 | 2018-01-27 08:04:57.035831
(1 row)
```

Comment: we're using Hasura and this answer works when using Hasura's web console to set the default value for an *EXISTING* column (presumably due to the ::interval cast)

Answer (score 2):

Just use that as the default expression:

```
create table token
(
   id integer primary key,
   token text,
   expires timestamp default current_timestamp + interval '8' hour
);
```